# Simple LOTTERY Algorithm on PYTHON

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, random

İ want different numbers.I'm writing small number for example (10) in range it's working no problem but if i m writing a big number it can not work.

```
import random
arr=[]

for i in range(25):
    a=random.randint(1,30)
    if a in arr:
        b=random.randint(1,30)
        arr.append(b)
    if a not in arr:
        arr.append(a)
arr.sort()
print(arr[0:])
```

Comment: you mean it takes forever? not reall ysurprising. Which big value did you try?

Comment: you generate a random number, see if it's in there, then keep trying to generate a NEW random number... which means you have random time curves. **MAYBE** if you "win" the lotto, you'll generate a random number that's not already in the array, but as you fill up the array, the odds of that happening go down. Why can't you just fill an array with `1->n` numbers, shuffle it, then pop off however many numbers you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for lottery sample you should use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is already implemented in `random.shuffle` function. It is O(n) instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your method is that after if a is in arr, it appends another random number, b, which could be the same as a.

I would use the following method:

```
random.sample(xrange(1,30), 25)
```

If you really want a loop, then it should be like this:

```
arr=[]
for i in range(25):
    a=random.randint(1,30)
    while a in arr:
        a=random.randint(1,30)
    arr.append(a)
arr.sort()
print(arr[0:])
```